# App is using previous version of code after clearing storage

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I have very weird problem in my android application, Whenever I cleared data of app then it starts using code of previous version...

Ex :  I've set yellow background color to button and then run it and it runs successfull and I can see yellow color on Button...

After that I changed my code and lets say I've set blue background color to button and then run the app, app run successfully and I can see blue color on Button...

Then I cleared storage of an app from setting, and after that I open app and it shows yellow color, I need to compile and run again to see latest output.

Actully I am working of an application where it is in developing phase so I haven't included Log Out button, so whenever I need to test code from different account then I cleared storage and login again with different account, But then I need to compile and run again...

I am new to android development, But I guess it shouldn't happen...

I dont have any idea why it is happening, so I haven't tried anything yet.

EDIT : Here are screenshots of issue from my app

I changed this code, which basically format the time

```
val f = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault())
```

to this

```
val f = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm", Locale.getDefault())
```

and then run the application, 1st time

[1st image after changing format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ytlC.png)

As you can see time formate has changed, there is no AM or PM at the end
After that I cleared storage and sign in with different account
and I got this

[2nd time after clearing storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrEOC.png)

As you can see I hadnt change any code still I got previous compiled code which has different format.

Comment: If you install/update your app by pressing the run button in Android Studio not always a new app is generated. AS has the capability to patch updates until the app at run-time. May be those patches are affected if you clear app data. If you want to make sure a full version is installed via AS you can use the terminal and execute `./gradlew installDebug`

Comment: What have you tried so far in code? Please edit your question and add the code that doesn't work the way you expect. Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo The code is working fine after I install app 2nd time, and right now I am working on social media like application in which I changed some code in chat section and It was working fine untill I cleared storage to sign in with different account, and When I signed in then code was not working, So, I reinstall application and then code was again working perfect. Then I tried in other code and again the same problem occurs.

Comment: @AlexMamo Hey, I edited my question , also add screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried completely deleting the application from the device and re-installing it instead of clearing storage?

Comment: Yes but ofcourse It will use stored code from build APK, so it is not changing, But IDK why clearing storage is making my app go to the previous version